# Is there a shortcut format for specifying a git <stash>? e.g. stash@{3}

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a shortcut format for specifying a `git <stash>`? e.g. `stash@{3}`

Like:

`git apply @3`

Instead of:

`git apply stash@{3}`

I did not see anything in the man file:

> When no <stash> is given, stash@{0} is assumed, **otherwise <stash>
>   must be a reference of the form
>              stash@{<revision>}.**

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the man page lies a bit: you can give any "sufficiently stash-like" specifier.  Actual stash refs, like `stash` and `stash@{3}`, are always "stash-like" by definition.  However, any object name-able by `$REV` where:

- `$REV^2` exists
- `$REV`, `$REV^1`, `$REV:`, `$REV^1:`, and `$REV^2:` are all parse-able

is considered to be a stash.  The colon suffix turns a commit ID into a tree ID (making sure it exists), and:

- the stash itself is whatever ID `$REV` parses-out to
- the work-tree commit is `$REV`
- the "base" commit is `$REV^1`
- the work-tree tree is `$REV:`
- the base tree is `$REV^1:`
- the index-tree is `$REV^2:`

If `$REV^3` exists, it is the untracked/ignored files commit and its tree is `$REV^3:`.

What this means is that `git stash` will believe that any "real" merge commit is a stash.  (But applying them as stashes is weird at best. :-) )

If you want to be able to name a saved stash later by a short name, you can give it another name, e.g., a tag-name:

```
git tag foo stash@{3}
```

Note that this copies the *value* of `stash@{3}`, not the name: if you next push another stash, the commit (now referenced by a tag) will match `stash@{4}`.  You can see this by using `git rev-parse`:

```
git rev-parse foo; git rev-parse stash@{3}
```

will print the same giant SHA-1 value twice before you stash something new, and then:

```
git rev-parse foo; git rev-parse stash@{4}
```

will do the same after you stash something else, pushing another stash on the "stash stack".

You can create names outside the branch and tag space (or even outside `refs/` entirely) with `git update-ref`, and they work:

```
git update-ref refs/jinkies/scooby stash
git stash show jinkies/scooby
```

but I don't recommend doing this "manually", it's too easy to goof up here.  Using tags (and naming them such that you can remember what they were for, should you come across a leftover stash tag weeks or months after making a bunch in a coding frenzy) is probably more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `stash@{n}` *is* the shortcut for a commit object. In a repo of mine, I did this:

```
git show stash@{1}
```

amd I got this:

```
commit 24774ab81ad6c8f0b071363f62bf438572a2b286
Merge: 1c47ddf 31ae746
Author: Roberto Bonvallet <roberto@...>
Date:   Fri Oct 18 13:15:44 2013 -0300
```

So, in this case, `stash@{0}` is a shortcut for `24774ab81ad6c8f0b071363f62bf438572a2b286`.